# PDF stamping is not working in pages where does not have header info or body

Tags: c#, itext

Using the below code pdf stamping is working fine but if the pdf page does not have header info or body is empty then stamping is not working I mean pdfData.ShowText(strCustomMessage) is not working.

```
//create pdfreader object to read sorce pdf
PdfReader pdfReader=new PdfReader(Server.MapPath("Input") + "/" + "input.pdf");
//create stream of filestream or memorystream etc. to create output file
FileStream stream = new FileStream(Server.MapPath("Output") + "/output.pdf",  FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
//create pdfstamper object which is used to add addtional content to source pdf file
PdfStamper pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader,stream);
//iterate through all pages in source pdf
for (int pageIndex = 1; pageIndex <= pdfReader.NumberOfPages; pageIndex++)
{
//Rectangle class in iText represent geomatric representation... in this case, rectanle object would contain page geomatry
Rectangle pageRectangle = pdfReader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(pageIndex);
//pdfcontentbyte object contains graphics and text content of page returned by pdfstamper
PdfContentByte pdfData = pdfStamper.GetUnderContent(pageIndex);
//create fontsize for watermark
pdfData.SetFontAndSize(BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA_BOLD, BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED), 40);
//create new graphics state and assign opacity
PdfGState graphicsState = new PdfGState();
graphicsState.FillOpacity = 0.4F;
//set graphics state to pdfcontentbyte
pdfData.SetGState(graphicsState);
//set color of watermark
pdfData.SetColorFill(BaseColor.BLUE);
//indicates start of writing of text
pdfData.BeginText();
//show text as per position and rotation
pdfData.SetTextMatrix(pageRectangle.Width/2,pageRectangle.Height/2);                                                                                     pdfData.SetFontAndSize(BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA, BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED), 9);
string strCustomMessage="PDF Stamping Test"
pdfData.ShowText(strCustomMessage);
//call endText to invalid font set
pdfData.EndText();
}
//close stamper and output filestream
pdfStamper.Close();
stream.Close();
```

Comment: *is not working* - in which way is it not working?

Answer (score 0):

I think your question is wrong. Would do you mean when you say *"the pdf page does not have header info or body is empty"*? Because that doesn't make sense.

A few observations: I think you're using an obsolete version of iTextSharp. [Read the FAQ](http://itextpdf.com/salesfaq) to find out why this is a bad idea.

Newer versions of iTextSharp will throw an exception because of this error:

```
pdfData.BeginText();
//show text as per position and rotation
string strCustomMessage="PDF Stamping Test"
pdfData.ShowText(strCustomMessage);
//call endText to invalid font set
pdfData.EndText();
```

In these lines, you are violating the PDF reference: you are showing text within a BT/ET sequence without defining a font and size. Had you used a newer version of iTextSharp, an exception would have pointed that out. You need to move the line with the `SetFontAndSize()` method *inside* the `BeginText()`/`EndText()` sequence. It's illegal to use it outside a text object.

Also: why are you using `BeginText()`/`EndText()` to add text? That is code for **PDF specialists**. Read the documentation to find out how to use `ColumnText.ShowTextAligned()`. The `ShowTextAligned()` method is a convenience method written for developer who aren't fluent in PDF syntax.

Whether or not the text added with `ShowText()` is visible will depend on:

- *the opacity of the page:* Suppose that your page consists of a scanned image, you won't see any text, because you're adding the text *under* the image. Use the `GetOverContent()` method instead of the `GetUnderContent()` method to avoid this.
- *the position on the page:* I see that you get the size of the page using the `GetPageSizeWithRotation()` method, but I don't see you doing anything with that info. I don't see at which coordinate you are showing the text. That is also wrong. You need to make sure that you add the text inside the visible area of the page.

This answer lists several problems with your code. It would be better if you simplify your code by using the `ShowTextAligned()` and correct X,Y coordinates.